# I am trying to return just the amount of days between deadline and launch date. However it is returning the hours minutes and seconds as well

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-difference

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Datasets/KickstarterRevised.csv')
df['deadline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['deadline'])
df['launched'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['launched'])

df['difference'] = df['deadline'].sub(df['launched'], axis=0)
df['difference']
```

```
0      58 days 23:24:00
1      45 days 00:00:00
2      30 days 01:00:00
3      55 days 16:25:00
4      35 days 00:00:00
             ...       
4994   40 days 00:00:00
4995    8 days 10:50:00
4996   38 days 18:53:00
4997   30 days 00:00:00
4998   30 days 00:00:00
Name: difference, Length: 4999, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: To get days, you could use the `days` attribute of the timedelta, or `.total_seconds()/86400` to get fractional days. You can access both via the `dt` accessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see from your code, `df['difference']` is a Series with `dtype: timedelta64[ns]`. To get the days, just use `.astype("timedelta64[D]")`, see below

```
df['difference'] = df['deadline'].sub(df['launched'], axis=0).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```